# Add/Enable timestamp to Dask scheduler/workers console logs

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

Is there a way to add/enable timestamp to Dask scheduler/workers console logs.?

dask:             0.15.0-py35_0
distributed:      1.17.1-py35_0

If I use the above versions this is not enabled -

Scheduler -

```
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at: tcp://192.168.200.23:8600
distributed.scheduler - INFO -       bokeh at:       192.168.200.23:8620
distributed.scheduler - INFO -        http at:       192.168.200.23:8610
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Local Directory: /jenkins_VegaFarm_edi-vf-3-4/workspace/AutoBATS/tmp/5896310/cbecb324-9b7c-46af-8ed7-5075aab3f225
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:33876
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:43544
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:43675
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:39567
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:33450
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:42608
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:36773
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.200.23:43157
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp:/
```

Workers -

```
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:33621'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:42826'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:37509'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:36526'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:46298'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:36025'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:46421'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:36029'
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://192.168.200.23:41999'
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at: tcp://192.168.200.23:33876
distributed.worker - INFO -              nanny at:       192.168.200.23:44329
distributed.worker - INFO -               http at:       192.168.200.23:34181
distributed.worker - INFO -              bokeh at:       192.168.200.23:8789
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:  tcp://192.168.200.23:8600
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at: tcp://192.168.200.23:33450
distributed.worker - INFO -              nanny at:       192.168.200.23:39203
```

Is there any way I can prefix timestamp to these logs.? This will help in debugging some internal crashes.

Kind regards, Jacob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a log formatting string in your `~/.dask/config.yaml` file.  Here is the current default that results in your current logs:

```
distributed:
  admin:
    log-format: '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

See [logging module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) for more formatting options

Comment: I tried adding the line, but Dask doesn't seem to pick it up.                                                                                                              log-format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

Comment: This feature seems to be hardcoded in function initialize_logging() from 
 file distributed/config.py. I had to manually edit the format of the function to get it working - fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'. Is this fixed in the latest version of Dask?

Comment: This definitely works in master.  I haven't checked to see how far back it goes.

Comment: Thanks, tested on Distributed version 1.17.1 and works as suggested.

Comment: Just to clarify: The fully-qualified name for this configuration setting is `distributed.admin.log-format`